# How can I configure font foreground color in eclipse popup dialog

Tags: ubuntu, eclipse

How can I configure font foreground color in eclipse popup dialog under ubuntu 11.10?
I am seeing white foreground over light grey text which makes it very hard to read.

How can I fix that?

Comment: Not really sure what you mean. Can you post a screenshot?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Eclipse Colour Theme [plugin](http://www.eclipsecolorthemes.org/?view=plugin)